# unable to login to OpenERP7

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I am stuck in really weird problem, and i am unable to figure out the cause of the problem. i have OpenERP installed on my development environment and production environment, both on Ubuntu. On Dev site all is working fine. Earlier yesterday, on production it was working ok. but all of a sudden i started getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create'
```

here is the full trace of the error from pop up:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
        response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 867, in authenticate
        req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 115, in authenticate
        uid = self.proxy('common').authenticate(db, login, password, env)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
        result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
        raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


    Server Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
        return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
        result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 433, in dispatch
        return fn(*params)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 444, in exp_authenticate
        res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
        return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
        registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 192, in get
        update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 218, in new
        openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 435, in load_modules
        model._register_hook(cr)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base_action_rule/base_action_rule.py", line 201, in _register_hook
        model_obj.create = self._wrap_create(model_obj.create, model)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create'
```

after i close popup i am still on my openERP login form.

I am not sure what actually has happened. All i was trying to change my modules UI using view.xml. I used this xml file to recreate this issue on my dev server, but on my dev server it is working perfectly. Plz let me know if this is because of permission issue(though i cant remember messing around with permissions).

Plz let me know what i am doing wrong. If any furthur info is needed, feel free to ask for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem on an Action Rule.
Try deactivating them to see if you can login.

Open `psql` or a pgAdmin Query window, and run:

```
update base_action_rule set active = 'f'
```

Then later on go to Configuration -> Technical -> Automated Actions, and make an Advanced Filter: Active is False, so you can see them and try to find the cause for the problem.

A more drastic solution is to temporarily rename the base_action_rule directory in the addons directory and restart the server. You will get a warning because the module won't be loaded, but the server will start.

Comment: Well just want to know, what was actual problem? Running update to `base_action_rule` worked for me.